# RenderBox Error with CarouselSlider and ListView: RenderRepaintBoundary#83bf7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to get a result like the image attached below. However, when the welcome.dart file is executed, the following error appears.
If I return the carousel and listview independently, there is no error.

[image: I wanna get this screen]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  const Welcome({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _WelcomeState createState() => _WelcomeState();
}

class _WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffdfe1e8),
  body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.15),
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: screenHeight * 0.6,
          child: Image.asset('assets/bg/splash.png'),
        ),
      ]),
  persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListView(
                  children: [
                    CarouselSlider(
                      items: const [
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                      ],

                      //Slider Container properties
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: 180.0,
                        // enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2 / 1,
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.linear,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                        autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                            Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                        viewportFraction: 1,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                   children: [
                     OutlinedButton(
                         onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Skip')),
                     OutlinedButton(
                         onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Next')),
                   ],
                ),
              ],
            )),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> This is Error

[image: Error screenshot]

As someone new to Flutter, I'm going crazy because I can't figure out why.
I've googled a lot, but there doesn't seem to be a solution that works for my situation.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by providing width on `SizedBox` and while we don't need extra `ListView` we can remove this. And use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` on row to get the UI. Also, you can use `LayoutBuilder` on body to get constraints in replace of `MediaQuery`.

```dart
class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  const Welcome({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _WelcomeState createState() => _WelcomeState();
}

class _WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffdfe1e8),
      body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.15),
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight * 0.6,
              child: Image.asset('assets/bg/splash.png'),
            ),
          ]),
      persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // ListView(
                    //   children: [
                    CarouselSlider(
                      items: const [
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                        Text(
                            'Tad asdfnwei asedftdoi vasdfazsdd asdfasd asdfasd sdfsfd  asdfasf a sadfdsfdsfad adfadfa adsfadfef  adsfadsfaf asdfafe4rfsdfvsdaf  afe4f adsfafaaf'),
                      ],

                      //Slider Container properties
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        height: 180.0,
                        // enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 2 / 1,
                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.linear,
                        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                        autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                        viewportFraction: 1,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      ),
                      //   ),
                      // ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        OutlinedButton(
                            onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Skip')),
                        OutlinedButton(
                            onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Next')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Yeasin Sheikh. You are amazing expert.

Comment: How can I add dot indicator under the carousel?

Comment: you need to create another row with dots/container and scale based on active index. [this might help you](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/Utils/custionDotIndicator.dart)